# Highcharts, get point index when shared tooltip is shows/hides

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I have a group of charts which have the same categories.

When user hover on the chart and the tooltip is shown, I need to set all charts's corresponding point state to hover to help user to compare the data.

Firstly I use `mouseOver` and `mouseOut` events and it almost meet my needs, but I use shared tooltip so sometimes the tooltip shows without mouse on the point, so the event is not fired.

So I guess I need an event that when the tooltip shows/hides, and I find [this](http://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-highcharts-javascript-api/suggestions/4473722-add-after-tooltip-show-event) and try `tooltipRefresh` event but I can't find the exactly index of on which point the tooltip shows. I have tried:

```
tooltipRefresh: function(e) {
    var index = this.hoverPoint.index; //No dependentable
}
```

Is that any way that I can get the index at the right event firing moment?

Comment: Do you  mean something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/94v3wL6u/1/ (hover on a point in first chart)

Answer (score 0):

you can use Label which just like the tootip, show X, Y value on the Lable.

What i did is :

```
    1.click on one chart  === >  
    2.get X value  ===>  
    3.fire a Event (click event of chart)  === >  
    4.render Label on every other chart using X (get Y value in each chart by X)
```

when create chart, I set an click event

```
options.chart = $.extend(true, options.chart, {
                renderTo: 'hChart_' + chartIndex,
                type: 'spline',
                events: {
                    click: function (event) {
                        if($scope.label.length > 0){
                            $scope.clearAllLabels();
                        }else{
                            var charts = $scope.ui.charts;
                            $.each(charts, function (index, chart) {
                                //render Label to chart
                             });
                        }
                     }
                   }
                });
```

Below is add label in chart.

```
var label = chart.renderer.label(
                    moment(xAxis).format('dddd, MMM DD, HH:mm:ss') + '<br>' + kpiName + ': <b>' + Highcharts.numberFormat(yAxis, 2) + kpiUnit + '</b>',
                    120,
                    40)
                .attr({
                    fill: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0],
                    padding: 10,
                    r: 5,
                    zIndex: 8
                })
                .css({
                    lineHeight: '20%',
                    fontSize: '11px',
                    color: '#FFFFFF'
                })
                .add();
```

Hope it will help you.